# What content i can put in keyphrase Meta Tags?

Tags: html

In my website project, I added below meta tags.

I have some doubts in meta tags,.

1. What I add the Content in keyphrase meta
2. Is these meta tags are enough or I Miss any important Meta Tag?

Please Give suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
<!-- Meta -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="MCUBIC SOLUTIONS in chennai providers of Hospitality Management Softwares,KIOSK and ERP Solutions world wide  " />
        <meta name="keywords" content="MCUBIC SOLUTIONS,Hotel Management Software,Hospitality Software,Kiosk,Digital signage systems,Wireless internet solution providers,Mobile pos,ERP solutions,Property Management Software,Centralized Reservation System for Hospitality,CRS,Payroll Management" />
        <meta name="abstract" content="" />
        <!--<meta name="keyphrase" content="" />-->
        <meta name="classification" content="Web Design and Web Development Company, Bangalore, Vellore, Chennai India" />
        <meta name="robots" content="all" />
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
        <meta name="author" content=" www.mcubicsolutions.com"/>
        <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days"/>
        <!-- ENDS Meta -->
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest - I wouldn't care so much about the meta tags, since many search-engines like google don't use the meta-tag keywords for example.
It is much more important, that your website is valide!
User http://validator.w3.org for example to check your code.

I would delete 'classifiaction' and 'abstract' tag.

See also: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#standard-metadata-names